# Replace password in connection string with regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression in C# that will replace the password of a connection string so that it is not shown when I display it on a page.  The connection string password are somewhere in the string as PWD=password;

So far I have:

```
Regex.Replace(connStr, "PWD=.*;", "PWD=********");
```

This works to find the beginning of the pattern, but the problem is the wild card (.*) is also including the ; so the pattern is never terminated and the remainder of the string is replaced too.  How can I say everthing but a ; in my RegEx?

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious - I'm sure you have a good reason - but why would you *ever* show even a partial connection string on your web page?

Comment: It's for an admin webapp.  Admins can modify connection strings via the app, but I don't want them to see the passwords on the list page.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a non-greedy quantifier:

```
PWD=.*?;
```

Or exclude `;`s:

```
PWD=[^;]*;
```

Comment: That's what I was missing.  Thanks!

Comment: In the event it's the last item and not trailed by a semicolon you should probably use: PWD=([^;]*)(?:$|;)

Comment: That's a good point.  I also changed PWD= to (PWD=|pwd=) to make it case insensitve.

Comment: @Paul: That's not case insensitive. Passing `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` is case insensitive :)

Comment: @minitech: Cool!  I didn't even know that was an option.  Just started in C# this week. ;)

Comment: also as noted below in another answer it might appear as PASSWORD instead of PWD, make sure you account for both

Comment: I used this variant... $"({key})=([^;]*)(?:$|;)";   so I can pass a connection string keyword to the regex and mask whatever e.g.
    var keys = new string[] { "PASSWORD", "PWD", "USER ID", "UID", "DATA SOURCE", "DSN" };
                foreach (string key in keys)
                {
                    pat = $"({key})=([^;]*)(?:$|;)";

Answer (score 29):

You don't need to use RegEx for this - .NET has the built-in [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) class which you can use to get values from the connection string and change them.

Example code:

```
string conString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;";
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(conString);

builder.Password = "********";

Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

Comment: I don't know Oracle, so I can't tell for sure. But I just googled a bit and found the [OracleConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) which looks like what you're looking for. It's deprecated and will be removed in the future, though...[Microsoft suggests to use a 3rd party provider in the future](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. If I remeber this project (it's been a while) the connection string could have been for any DMBS, not just MSSQL.  But thanks for the tip.  Good to know.

Comment: Who says it is deprecated?  Seems to be in the latest ODP.NET I have for 12c??\

Comment: "Deprecated" means "will be removed at some point". I don't remember the exact wording in the MSDN link that I posted >6 years ago, but now it redirects to learn.microsoft.com, and [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnectionstringbuilder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks) it says "This type is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the .NET Framework. For more information, see [Oracle and ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet?view=netframework-4.8)."

Comment: Oh, and the second link in my comment directly redirects to the "Oracle and ADO.NET" page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex I'm using

```
(?<=Password=).+?(?=(;|'|"|$))
```

With positiv look behind to find the start of the password,
positiv look ahead to find the end of the Password and
a not greedy match Expression.
The "Detektion Tokens" (Password= ;'"$) might differ in varios scenarios.

[Testcases: https://regex101.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3xLr.jpg)

c# implementation

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
private static Regex _regex = new Regex("(?<=Password=).+?(?=(;|'|\"|$))");
//...
var decryptPwdMatch = _regex.Match("some connectionstring for example");
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

We came across this issue and a colleague came up with the following regex:

```
"(?i)(?:^|.*;)pwd=(\".*\"|.*?)(?:;|$)+?"
```

or

```
"(?i)(?:^|.*;)password=(\".*\"|.*?)(?:;|$)+?"
```

if there is password in it instead of pwd.

The Password matches with the following code:

```
            var regex = new Regex(mask);
            var password = string.Empty;
            var match = regex.Match(connectionString);
            if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count > 1)
            {
                password = match.Groups[1].Value;
            }
```

Comment: Careful; if the password is in quotes and something else is in quotes too, `.*` is going to match as much as possible. It should probably be `.*?` too. Also, the `(?:^|.*;)` could just be `(?<=^|;)` — probably more efficient.

Comment: and you can just do (pwd=|password=) for 1 magic regex!  But the best option is to use the ConnectionStringBuilder mentioned below...

Answer (score 0):

Lots of problems with the suggested solution. This is not pure Regex, but handles casing, white spaces and optional trailing separators (, or ;)

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string MaskField(this string str, string field, string mask = "***")
    {
        var separators = ",;";
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var keyValue in Regex.Split(str, $"(?<=[{separators}])"))
        {
            var temp = keyValue;
            var index = keyValue.IndexOf("=");
            if (index > 0)
            {
                var key = keyValue.Substring(0, index);
                if (string.Compare(key.Trim(), field.Trim(), true) == 0)
                {
                    var end = separators.Contains(keyValue.Last()) ? keyValue.Last().ToString() : "";
                    temp = key + "=" + mask + end;
                }
            }

            sb.Append(temp);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```